# how to get the shifted index value of a dataframe in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date-range, shift

Consider the simple example below:

```
date = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=5, freq='H')

df = pd.DataFrame({'cat' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B',
                         'B']}, index = date)
df
Out[278]: 
                    cat
2011-01-01 00:00:00   A
2011-01-01 01:00:00   A
2011-01-01 02:00:00   A
2011-01-01 03:00:00   B
2011-01-01 04:00:00   B
```

I want to create a variable that contains the lagged/lead value of the index. That is something like:

```
df['index_shifted']=df.index.shift(1)
```

So, for instance, at time `2011-01-01 01:00:00` I expect the variable `index_shifted` to be `2011-01-01 00:00:00`

How can I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: df.index gives  `etc etc '2016-06-13 16:29:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=2471070, freq=None)` Is this a problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need [`Index.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.shift.html) with `-1`:

```
df['index_shifted']= df.index.shift(-1)
print (df)
                    cat       index_shifted
2011-01-01 00:00:00   A 2010-12-31 23:00:00
2011-01-01 01:00:00   A 2011-01-01 00:00:00
2011-01-01 02:00:00   A 2011-01-01 01:00:00
2011-01-01 03:00:00   B 2011-01-01 02:00:00
2011-01-01 04:00:00   B 2011-01-01 03:00:00
```

For me it works without `freq`, but maybe it is necessary in real data:

```
df['index_shifted']= df.index.shift(-1, freq='H')
print (df)
                    cat       index_shifted
2011-01-01 00:00:00   A 2010-12-31 23:00:00
2011-01-01 01:00:00   A 2011-01-01 00:00:00
2011-01-01 02:00:00   A 2011-01-01 01:00:00
2011-01-01 03:00:00   B 2011-01-01 02:00:00
2011-01-01 04:00:00   B 2011-01-01 03:00:00
```

EDIT:

If `freq` of `DatetimeIndex` is `None`, you need add `freq` to `shift`:

```
import pandas as pd

date = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=5, freq='H').union(pd.date_range('5/1/2011', periods=5, freq='H'))


df = pd.DataFrame({'cat' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B',
                         'B','A', 'A', 'A', 'B',
                         'B']}, index = date)

print (df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2011-01-01 00:00:00', '2011-01-01 01:00:00',
               '2011-01-01 02:00:00', '2011-01-01 03:00:00',
               '2011-01-01 04:00:00', '2011-05-01 00:00:00',
               '2011-05-01 01:00:00', '2011-05-01 02:00:00',
               '2011-05-01 03:00:00', '2011-05-01 04:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

df['index_shifted']= df.index.shift(-1, freq='H')
print (df)
                    cat       index_shifted
2011-01-01 00:00:00   A 2010-12-31 23:00:00
2011-01-01 01:00:00   A 2011-01-01 00:00:00
2011-01-01 02:00:00   A 2011-01-01 01:00:00
2011-01-01 03:00:00   B 2011-01-01 02:00:00
2011-01-01 04:00:00   B 2011-01-01 03:00:00
2011-05-01 00:00:00   A 2011-04-30 23:00:00
2011-05-01 01:00:00   A 2011-05-01 00:00:00
2011-05-01 02:00:00   A 2011-05-01 01:00:00
2011-05-01 03:00:00   B 2011-05-01 02:00:00
2011-05-01 04:00:00   B 2011-05-01 03:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with `df['index_shifted']=df.index.shift(-1)`?

(Genuine question, not sure if I missed something)

Comment: I get `ValueError: Cannot shift with no freq`

Comment: @Noobie: weird, it works fine locally. What's the result of `df.index.freq`? It should be `<Hour>`.

Comment: please look at my comment above

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but if your timestamps have gaps or you do not want to specify the frequency, AND you are not dealing with timezones the following will work:

```
df['index_shifted'] = pd.Series(df.index).shift(-1).values
```

If you are dealing with Timezones the following will work:

```
df['index_shifted'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(df.index).shift(-1).values, utc=True).tz_convert('America/New_York')
```